# Transaction is not accessible when using JTA with JPA-compliant transaction access enabled

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

I have a Transaction Manager injected with `@PersistenceContext` context annotation. Every time I'm trying to start the transaction with `em.getTransaction().begin` I got an exception with the error message

```
Transaction is not accessible when using JTA with JPA-compliant transaction access enabled
```

I know that I should inject `UserTransaction` or use `@Transactional` annotation but I want to know the reason for such behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should inject a container managed transaction.

Something like:

```
@Resource
private UserTransaction transaction;

public method() {
  try {
     transaction.begin();
     ...do some persistence...
     transaction.commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     transaction.rollback();
  }
}
```

OR

if you don't need such control you can use @Transaction annotation on your method.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same issue but problem lied elsewhere...

So the stack: I was using Wildfly server , postgresql, and JPA

At first, my persistence.xml was configured to use RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions e.g.

```
<persistence-unit name="unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

and I had a problem that even when the method was marked `@Transactional` it was not doing any rollbacks when error occured, yet saving worked fine.

So then I decided to use transaction-type JTA instead of RESOURCE_LOCAL so that the container manages the transactions.

When I changed my persistence.xml to  this, it was still not working

```
<persistence-unit name="unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/unit</jta-data-source>
```

and was throwing the very error that is in the title of this question.

My problem was, how I was creating the EntityManager, this is how it was defined

```
@Produces
@PersistenceContext
private static EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(UNIT_NAME).createEntityManager()
```

The solution? I had to remove the annotation `@PersistenceContext`

P.s. for JTA transactions do not forget to tell wildfly about the datasource for example via CLI like this

```
data-source add --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/unit --name=MyDb --connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres  --driver-name=postgresql  --user-name=username --password=password
```